# project directory for sbt sub-projects

Tags: scala, sbt

can a sbt sub project have its own `project` directory? or only the root project can project directory with .scala helper files for the build?. Below is my current build scructure. The `/my-project/sub-projects/sub-project-1/build.sbt` is not able to access objects defined in `/my-project/sub-projects/sub-project-1/SubProjectHelper.scala`.

```
/my-project
  build.sbt
  /projects
    Helper.scala
  sub-projects
    sub-project-1
      build.sbt
      /projects
        SubProjectHelper.scala
```

**Update:**
The below sbt definition in sub-project-1/build.sbt

```
lazy val localhost = (project in file(".")).settings (
    name := """localhost""",
    version := Common.version,
    scalaVersion := Common.scalaVersion,
    libraryDependencies ++= Common.dependencies,
    libraryDependencies ++= Localhost.dependencies
)
```

is failing with the below error

```
    libraryDependencies ++= Localhost.dependencies
                            ^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.checkError(Eval.scala:384)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.compileAndLoad(Eval.scala:183)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalCommon(Eval.scala:152)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalDefinitions(Eval.scala:122)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateDefinitions(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:271)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateSbtFile(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:109)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:712)
```

Common is defined in /my-project/projects/Common.scala and has no issues. But Localhost is defined in /my-project/sub-projects/sub-project-1/projects/SubProjectHelper.scala is not properly resolved in the sub-project-1 build.sbt

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can, and you even don't need to have `sub-projects` dir, just place `sub-project-1` in `my-project` dir.

Comment: I have updated the question to add more info. can you let me know what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Usually (at least this is what *scala/scala-seed.g8* ends up with) project subdirectory doesn't ends with an extra *s* like your directory structure.

You should rename `projects` to `project`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, unfortunately. As seen [here](https://docs.huihoo.com/sbt/0.12.4/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html)

> You cannot have a project subdirectory or project/*.scala files in the sub-projects. foo/project/Build.scala would be ignored.